# ebpf hook some points, after running for a while. the system is hang ,is kernel bug?

Tags: kernel, ebpf

sched_switch, sched_wakeup, ipi_entry ipi_exit when hook this points, after running for a while. the system is hang ,is kernel bug ?   the kernel is 5.4

look for call stacks in hang core:
Non-secure Watchdog data
Pet time: 9.36s
Bark time: 12.0s
Watchdog last pet: 10501.000
CPU online bits: 11111111
CPU runqueue online bits: 11111111
CPU isolated bits: 00000000
pet_timer_flags: 0x22800005
pet_timer_expires: 4297519716
Current jiffies  : 4297532602
Timestamp of last timer interrupt(last_jiffies_update): 10561.224
tick_do_timer_cpu: 2
CPU logical map: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
epoch_ns: 10444197478329ns  epoch_cyc: 1749340041338
CPU#0 : ping_start: 10556.653275 : ping_end: 0.000000

is CPU 0 :

FP:0xffffffc022f339f0:0xffffffc022f33a30 PC:0xffffffc022f339f8:('bpf_ktime_get_ns', 16)
FP:0xffffffc022f33aa0:0xffffffc022f33ac0 PC:0xffffffc022f33aa8:('trace_call_bpf', 132)
FP:0xffffffc022f33ac0:0xffffffc022f33b20 PC:0xffffffc022f33ac8:('perf_trace_run_bpf_submit', 84)
FP:0xffffffc022f33b20:0xffffffc022f33b90 PC:0xffffffc022f33b28:('perf_trace_sched_switch$1cd8070f38e3a69b94547dfaa5326063', 384)
FP:0xffffffc022f33b40:0xffffffc022f33ba0 PC:0xffffffc022f33b48:('__switch_to', 148)
FP:0xffffffc022f33b80:0xffffffc022f33ba0 PC:0xffffffc022f33b88:('__switch_to', 276)
FP:0xffffffc022f33b90:0xffffffc022f33c00 PC:0xffffffc022f33b98:('__schedule', 1668)
FP:0xffffffc022f33ba0:0xffffffc022f33c00 PC:0xffffffc022f33ba8:('__schedule', 1048)
FP:0xffffffc022f33c00:0xffffffc022f33c60 PC:0xffffffc022f33c08:('schedule', 140)
FP:0xffffffc022f33c60:0xffffffc022f33c80 PC:0xffffffc022f33c68:('futex_wait_queue_me', 132)
FP:0xffffffc022f33c80:0xffffffc022f33d80 PC:0xffffffc022f33c88:('futex_wait', 292)
FP:0xffffffc022f33d80:0xffffffc022f33df0 PC:0xffffffc022f33d88:('do_futex', 216)
FP:0xffffffc022f33df0:0xffffffc022f33e20 PC:0xffffffc022f33df8:('__arm64_sys_futex', 172)
FP:0xffffffc022f33e20:0xffffffc022f33e70 PC:0xffffffc022f33e28:('el0_svc_common', 196)
FP:0xffffffc022f33e70:0xffffffc022f33eb0 PC:0xffffffc022f33e78:('el0_svc_handler', 36)
FP:0xffffffc022f33eb0:0xffffffc022f33ff0 PC:0xffffffc022f33eb8:('el0_svc', 8)

Comment: What exact kernel version are you using? Could you share the BPF program(s) you are attaching?

Comment: kernel version is 5.4 ，target is arm64 ：

Comment: DEFINE_BPF_PROG("tracepoint/sched/sched_switch", EBPF_UID, EBPF_GID,
                tp_sched_switch)
(struct trace_event_raw_sched_switch *ctx) {
  calc_OnCPU(ctx);
  calc_OffCPU(ctx);
  return EBPF_SUCCESS;
}

DEFINE_BPF_PROG("tracepoint/sched/sched_wakeup", EBPF_UID, EBPF_GID,
                tp_sched_wakeup)
(struct trace_event_raw_sched_wake *ctx) {
  trace_enqueue(ctx->pid);
  return EBPF_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: You can edit your post to add it in a readable way :-)

Comment: the code is here :  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bpfprogs/+/482dfa1ca63eb209866ff3a7b3aeb3daada7b4e1/time_in_state.c

Comment: is SEC("tracepoint/sched/sched_switch")